How can I use the FindFirstFile API in NASM to display the first EXE file in the directory?
I recently started coding in ASM with NASM. After a short Hello World, I wanted to code a short program that uses the FindFirstFile API and displays the first .EXE file in the current folder in a message box. I was able to assemble and link it with GoLink, but the program doesn't display a message box at all.
Here is my code that I have written so far:
extern FindFirstFileA
extern ExitProcess
extern MessageBoxA

[section .data use32]
    search_handle dd 0
    exe_mask db "*.exe"
    title db "Title"
    
    Win32data:
          FileAttributes           dd 0              ;attributes
          CreationTime             dd 0,0            ;time of creation
          LastAccessTime           dd 0,0            ;last access time
          LastWriteTime            dd 0,0            ;last modification
          FileSizeHigh             dd 0              ;filesize
          FileSizeLow              dd 0              ; "
          Reserved0                dd 0
          Reserved1                dd 0
          FileName                 dd 260          ;long filename
          AlternateFileName        dd 13           ;short filename


[SECTION CODE USE32 CLASS=CODE]
..start:
    push Win32data
    push exe_mask
    call [FindFirstFileA]
    mov [search_handle], eax
    
    push 0
    push title
    push FileName
    push 0
    call [MessageBoxA]
    
    push byte 0
    call [ExitProcess]
end

I used the following commands to assemble and link the file:
nasm -fobj find.asm
golink -oPE find win32.lib

I would appreciate it if someone could take a look and push me into the correct direction.

Your Win32data is not declared correctly. FileName and AlternateFileName should use db instead of dd, and the size of AlternateFileName should be 14 not 13. In any case, what is the value of search_handle after FindFirstFileA() returns? If it is 0xFFFFFFFF then the function failed and the content of Filename will be undefined.

extern FindFirstFileA, etc - all this bad declarations. use extern __imp__FindFirstFileA@8: DWORD (masm syntax, dont know how this be in nasm), etc. all this FindFirstFileA, ExitProcess, MessageBoxA.. is pointer size variables and have another names (begin with __imp_ and mangled)

Note that dd 260 does not allocate 260 dwords (much less bytes). It allocates a single dword with value 260. What you want is times (260) db 0. Similarly for the AlternateFileName which apparently should even be 14 not 13 bytes. And you are missing a couple more fields.

Also your exe_mask and title should be zero terminated.
